# What is real time priority of a process

Tags: linux

ps o/p gives rtprio and prio as well. Whats the difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the realtime scheduler (that means if an process runs controlled by the realtime scheduler), so the rtprio could be relevant. 
Prio is relevant for the default scheduler sched

Normally RT processes has system-wide the highest priority by default. If you need to tune/coordinate RT processes and non-RT processes, so rtprio and prio have to be tuned.

http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=rtprio
http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler