# rtprio and pri values range in Linux ps

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, ps

I generate a normal process and check with cmd:

```
ps -p [PID] -o uname, cmd, cls, pri, rtprio
```

and have result

```
USER   CMD     CLS  PRI RTPRIO

haivo  ./pro1  TS   17    -
```

as far as I know Linux just know priority from 0 - 139 and priority from 0-99 for realtime process, but `RTPRIO` not show "rt" which means that my process just a normal process, another way pri = 17 belongs realtime priority range while my process just normal process. There seems to be a conflict.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is real time priority of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732154/what-is-real-time-priority-of-a-process)

Comment: maybe you misunderstood my mean, "pri" is 17 is bellow realtime range while "rtprio" is null that mean this is normal process, I thought "pri" should be from 100-139. Why it is 17? this is my question.

Comment: `haivo     4328  2197 ./pro1                           TS   17  -`. Normal process still have pri = 17 while rtprio = null.

Comment: and I have mistake, priority from 0-139, not 0-140

Comment: Upvote, because the question is reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should focus on `CLS`-field of *`ps`*'s output. From [man ps](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html):

> CLS    class of the process. (alias policy, cls).
>
> **-**    not reported
>
> **TS** SCHED_OTHER
>
> **FF**  SCHED_FIFO
>
> ...

The ranges you talk about are from different scopes. The priority in `SCHED_OTHER` (`SCHED_NORMAL`) is often about the ***PR = 20 + NI*** formula, where NI is "[nice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix))" (between -20 and 19). But keep in mind - ***the formula is not always relevant***, Linux kernel can change the priority on its own logic (but "nice" will remain the same, it's just a hint for kernel).

Thus, the value you see is absolutely correct.

See also: [Very useful post about Linux nice and prio](https://superuser.com/questions/203657/difference-between-nice-value-and-priority-in-the-top-output)

Comment: I found the way to see nice value with right value regulated in document:
`cat /proc/sched_debug`
 information in here really show what I want. Seem PRI in here and PRI in ps command is difference, I need time to find out